# Can I still access my me.com e mail account when changing to a Samsung galaxy s4?

Tags: iphone

I am changing from a iPhone 4S to a Samsung galaxy s4.  I currently have a me.com e mail address. Will I still be able to use this if not with iPhone?

Answer (score 5):

**Certainly, you will.**

> iCloud Mail uses IMAP and SMTP standards supported by most modern email applications.

After switching the device, your account will remain. You will be able to access your mail via [iCloud website](https://www.icloud.com) on supported Android browser *(e.g., Google Chrome)* or set up mail client following [these instructions](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4864?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US).